# Why is there an option to create rules for ICMP Echo Reply within security groups?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-security-group

If we want to send ping from an EC2 instance there must be outbound rule (in security group attached to that instance) that allows echo requests. Since the security groups are stateful response traffic for that request will be allowed regardless of inbound rules. There’s no need for a specific inbound rule that will allow echo response. EC2 that is receiving this ping must have security group attached with an inbound rule allowing echo requests. Analogically, there’s no need for a specific outbound rule that will allow echo response.

So why is there an option to create rules for echo reply?

It looks like it doesn’t have any use.
The only thing that comes to my mind is to allow sending echo reply without receiving echo request, but this doesn’t seem practical or even correct use of ICMP.

Comment: Security group rules do not care about the details of the protocol (IP, ICMP, etc) or if your rule design makes sense. Rules are just building blocks. Therefore a good design will have both ALLOW and DENY rules.

Comment: In security forensics there are cases where you want to allow something in but block its response. Should AWS try to guess every use case for its rules? This would slow down the processing of rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no obvious reason why this option is permitted, other than perhaps for completeness, or because of unusual cases (admittedly, none come to mind) where an unsolicited echo reply might be expected or desirable.

As you indicated, the stateful nature of security group rules should make actually using this feature unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the right response above, yes for security groups being stateful, there is no need to add  *echo reply*. I believe this is relevant for **NACL configuration** which is stateless and requires both inbound and outbound rules to be explicitly added. So it means the NACL needs to have below and hence it makes sense here:

1. NACL inbound allow rule for *echo request*
2. NACL outbound allow rule for *echo reply*

It seems the *protocol* dropdown in AWS console UI is just using the same set of protocols as for *NACL* (maybe same UI component in console design) but of course no meaning for *echo reply* for stateful Security Group.